# Display timer in textview contain days, hours, minutes and seconds in android

Tags: android, timer

I am using countdown timer to show the left time in text view.It is working fine.
Below is the code:-\

```
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    Context mContext;

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }


    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {

        MainActivity.timeDisplay.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));


    }

    public void onFinish() {
        AutomaticCallRecorderStaticMethod.startRecording();

    }
}


    public String formatTime(long millis) {
    output = "";
    long seconds = millis / 1000;
    long minutes = seconds / 60;
    long hours=minutes/ 60;

    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    hours=hours%60;

    String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
    String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
    String hoursD=String.valueOf(hours);


    if (seconds < 10)
        secondsD = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10)
        minutesD = "0" + minutes;

    if (hours < 10)
        hoursD = "0" + hours;

    output = hoursD+" : "+minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
    return output;
}
```

Code to start the timer:-

```
counter = new MyCount (length, 10);
```

Everything is working fine. It shows the timer in text view like as 00:00:00
and the maximum limit is 59:59:59. It means only 60 hours. Now I want that the limit should be increased if the user select 3 days then the timer should start from 71:59:59 or something like that so that the finish() method of countdown timer should be called after 3 days.How can I do that??
Beside it I want to show number of days also in the below format:-

Days:Hours:minutes:seconds left .

How can I achieve that.Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can check the value,
if(millisec > 24* 60*60*60*10... )
if so, divide by 24 to get number of days..

(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //for counting days

or
int days = (int) (milliseconds / (1000*60*60*24));

Other method is,
You can map with calender object I think.. I am not sure.. just try it out..

Comment: Please elaborate your answer so that I can understand easily and if possible please edit the above code and provide me the new one.

Comment: (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //for counting days